# Display different usercontrol per class object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Say I have a handful of class objects in a list called **Attributes**. In my case I want to bind to this list and display different user controls per Class object. Is there a way to do this ?

The code below seems to display all classes regardless of their type, I would assume it not to display the item type if i don't have a datatemplate for it.

**Classes**

```
public class Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class FloatAttr : Attribute
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    private float minValue { get; set; }
    private float maxValue { get; set; }
}

public class IntAttr : Attribute
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    private float minValue { get; set; }
    private float maxValue { get; set; }
}

public class StringAttr : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class BoolAttr : Attribute
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="AssetList" ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:IntAttr}">
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Blue"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text=" "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:BoolAttr}">
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text=" "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are multiple questions in one, but I'll try to answer:

To make your class generic, you have to change it to:

```
public class Attribute<TValue>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you have to change the subclasses. There is no point in repeating the `Key` and `Value` properties since they will be inherited. So, as an example the `FloatAttr` class will look like this:

```
public class FloatAttr : Attribute<float>
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    private float minValue { get; set; }
    private float maxValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when you do this, you can't create `List<Attribute>` (because the `Attribute` class cannot exist without the type parameter). So, unless you have another base class, you will have to use `List<object>`.

In WPF, all you need to do is to define data templates for the classes. You can do this in a resource dictionary or on a control level. For example, on a window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:IntAttr}">
        <TextBlock>Int</TextBlock>
        <!-- Int-specific controls -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FloatAttr}">
        <TextBlock>Float</TextBlock>
        <!-- Float-specific controls -->
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Note that you have to define a XML namespace (here called `local`) to point to the namespace where the classes are defined.
Then, you simply bind the list of objects to any `ItemsControl`.

BTW, the `#` character is not a comment in C#.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how i would place this into my code. I've updated the code above to show what I've done. could you help please. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The MVVM way is to create a [ResourceDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx)

```
<ResourceDictionary .....>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Attribute}">
        <views:AttributeView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FloatAttr }">
        <views:FloatAttrView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type IntAttr }">
        <views:IntAttrView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

When of course there is a view (a User control) for each class. then you need to register the dictionary you created via:

```
ResourceDictionary MyResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
MyResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri(ResourceDictionarypath, UriKind.Relative);
if ((Application.Current != null) && (Application.Current.Resources != null))
{
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(MyResourceDictionary);
}
```

Or, alternatively, as user [Greg D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6932/greg-d) suggested, you can use a simpleDataTemplateSelector assigned to the ItemTemplateSelector to assign the correct template. This can be useful if you're working with a mapping that's a little more complex than a simple 1:1, or if you have multiple data templates associated with the same underlying VM.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a simple`DataTemplateSelector` assigned to the ItemTemplateSelector to assign the correct template. This can be useful if you're working with a mapping that's a little more complex than a simple 1:1, or if you have multiple data templates associated with the same underlying VM.

Comment: hey Noam, if i decide to go with the solution posted by Vesan, if i post my code could you show me where to place his code to get it working?